# Default directory

Tags: java, intellij-idea

How do I change the default directory where intellij clones a git repository

I changed the default directory option under Appearences->system settings->default directory but it did not work. How do I change the directory for cloned projects

Answer (score 0):

To change the default directory where IntelliJ IDEA clones a Git repository, you have to modify the project creation settings as following:

1. Open IntelliJ IDEA and go to `File` in the menu bar
2. Select `New` and then choose `Project from Version Control` followed by `Git`
3. In the `Clone Repository` dialog that appears, enter the Git repository URL as usual
4. Before clicking the `Clone` button, in the below part you can see `Directory` field that shows the default directory where the project will be cloned. By default, it's usually the user's home directory. Change that place to you preferred location.

[image]

Comment: I know how to change that. I want to change it such that the default dorectory always shows the new directory that I want to set instead of me manually setting it up every time.
Ex: current: c/users/username/somename
it should be changed to default for always as
c/users/username/somename/someothername

Comment: What do you mean by "manually setting every time?", you set once and every time you enter your IDE it's changing location to default again?

Comment: Yes everytime I clone a new project the default directory is back to the 1st location I want to set 2nd location as default directory

Comment: Are using ultimate or community edition? And did you also sign into your GitHub account from the IDE?

Comment: I am using community edition and I have not signed with github account, I use the first tab Repository URL section to clone

Comment: Please try by singing into your GitHub account. Because in my case, I use Ultimate version and also singed in to GitHub, whenever I restart the IDE my preset Directory path doesn't change~

Answer (score 0):

Path shown here is the latest path used when cloning a project.
Did you try to clone something in your desired path and then to clone another project?

If this does not work, exit your IDE, locate your config file as shown on: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs

In `$config/options/vcs.xml` delete: `<option name="cloneParentDir" value="" />`

Comment: The file is now `$config/options/vcs-inputs.xml` (IntelliJ IDEA 2023.2, Community Edition). Don't delete the option, set the value to the directory that you want it to default to.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the clue from Dino Letic's answer, the configuration is in `$config/options/vcs-inputs.xml`.

Exit your IDE, [locate your config files](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs), and open `options/vcs-inputs.xml`. Find the `cloneParentDir` option, and set the `value` to the directory that you want to default to.